# How to add a json array into a property of a JObject with json.net

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I am having difficulty figuring out how to add an array of json objects to an existing `JObject`. Say I have a `JObject` with just the "Modified" property, and I want to add another property "IntersectGroups" that contains an array of json objects, how can I do this? I Have a `JObject[]` that when I serialize it is exactly in the format I require, but I am looking for something like this: `mainJObject.Add("IntersectGroups", myJObjectArray)`

Here is an example of the final json I want when I serialize it.

```
...
"Modified": "2012-11-26T10:21:04.693",
"IntersectGroups": [
  {
    "Id": 1004,
    "UserId": 20003,
    "GroupId": 1001,
    "Admin": false,
    "Expires": "1900-01-01T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "Id": 1003,
    "UserId": 20003,
    "GroupId": 1000,
    "Admin": false,
    "Expires": "1900-01-01T00:00:00"
  }
]
...
```

**UPDATE**

My final solution was to use the JArray object. A JArray is a JContainer, which is a JToken, which you can add to a JObject. My problem was that I was trying to use a JObject[], which was not a valid JToken

Comment: i'm thinking all you need to do is serialize the object to a string, then concatenate them and deserialize to a class that supports them.

Comment: I think this could work, I'll give it a go, thanks for the idea

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My final solution was to use the `JArray` object. A `JArray` is a `JContainer`, which is a `JToken`, which you can add to a `JObject`. My problem was that I was trying to use a `JObject[]`, which was not a valid `JToken`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `PopulateObject()` method, it has a good example of how to do this:

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/PopulateObject.htm

Comment: Seems like this is one of the only ways to do it.. kinda silly imo that there's no way to do what I'm after other than creating an object with compatible data types first, regardless thanks for digging this up.